# lag in udp streaming for videoview android

Tags: android, streaming, android-videoview

I'm playing streaming in videoview but every how many seconds it lag/paused then play again, how can I play video streaming smoothly for android. Here's my code:

```
vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);      
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
vv.setMediaController(mc);
Uri video = Uri.parse("udp://@239.239.1.1:1234");
vv.setVideoURI(video);
vv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

 @Override
 public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 vv.start();
 }
```

});

Comment: UDP is not natively supported: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html My advice would be to move to HTTP/RTSP if possible

Comment: ok ill try rtsp thanks Ken Wolf

Comment: in http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?23635-RTSP-issues-on-Android-4-x-series says Android 4.x does not stream RTSP, I'm using 4.2.2 version of Android